# Button in custom TableviewCell not accepting the action.when I tap on retry button it throws exc_bad_access signal .

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.section == 0){
    UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
    if (indexPath.row < kTotalScreens) {
        if ([self.tableCellsPrecreated count]>=kTotalScreens) {
            cell = [self.tableCellsPrecreated objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

    }
    return cell;
}else
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIDForHome];
    if (indexPath.row < [_subActionArray count])
    {
        if(cell == nil)
        {
        cell = [self getCellForCategoryActionForRow];
        NSLog(@"************cell %d created",indexPath.row);
        }
        GridViewController *controller = [self getControllerForCategoryActionCellAtIndex:indexPath.row
                                                                                 andCell:(TitleWithGridViewCell*)cell];
        [self reloadDataForController:controller
                      contentCategory:((CategoryAction *)[_subActionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).category
                             cellView:(TitleWithGridViewCell*)cell];
    }
    return cell;
}
}


-(UITableViewCell*)getCellForCategoryActionForRow
{
TitleWithGridViewCell* cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TitleWithGridViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
CGRect frameCell = cell.contentView.bounds;
frameCell.size.height = [cell heightOfCellForSubCellofSize:CellSizeSmall viewClass:[EntityCellView class] numRows:1];
[cell setFrame:frameCell];
cell.delegate = self;
cell.accessibilityLabel =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Category Channels Grid"];
return cell;
}

-(GridViewController*)getControllerForCategoryActionCellAtIndex :(NSInteger)index andCell:(TitleWithGridViewCell*)cell
{
GridViewController* gridController = nil;
CellViewFactory *channelCellFactory = [[CellViewFactory alloc] initWithWantedCellSize:CellSizeSmall cellViewClass:[EntityCellView class]];
ChannelsForCategoryDataFetcher *channelsForCategoryDataFetcher = [ChannelsForCategoryDataFetcher new];
PrefetchingDataSource *dataSource = [PrefetchingDataSource createWithDataFetcher:channelsForCategoryDataFetcher];
dataSource.sortBy = ProgramSortByRatingCount;
dataSource.objectsPrPage = 6;
if (cell) {
    gridController = [[GridViewController alloc] initWithGridView:[cell getGridView] gridCellFactory:channelCellFactory dataSource:dataSource];
    gridController.delegate = self;
}
return gridController;
}
```

Above code create one custom tableviewcell and the controller  for that cell.Every cell contains a try again button an case of network failure.Table is showing all the data and cells absolutely fine.But on taping try again button in cell it shows exc_bad_access.

Comment: Where is the code for try again button ?

Answer (score 1):

**At your Custom Cell End,**

1) Make protocol of your custom cell's .h file like

```
@protocol CustomCellDelegate
@optional
- (void)tryAgainButtonTappedOnCell:(id)sender;
@end
```

2) Set delegate in your .h file and set Custom Cell's button on click method

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<CustomCellDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)tryAgainButtonTapped:(id)sender;
```

3) In your .m file,

```
- (IBAction)tryAgainButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate tryAgainButtonTappedOnCell:self];
}
```

4) Link that IBAction with Button

5) Uncheck Use Autolayout of your Custom Cell

**At your Table View end,**

1) Set Delegate of Custom Cell

```
@interface SomeViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomCellDelegate>
```

2) In `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`, set the cell's delegate `cell.delegate=self`.

3) Implement new made Delegate's function according to your need i.e.

```
- (void)tryAgainButtonTappedOnCell:(id)sender
{
//your logic
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Cheers

Comment: Its already done.The cell have a grid view and a loading view.Loading view has retry button.It is failing on taping before calling the delegate in the grid view. But when I am pre-creating the cell and controller for cell and put them into arrays and implementing it like section 0 in the table it works fine.